# Getting a substr of a {{ var }} in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am populating a HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Event Title</th>
            <th>Event snippet</th>
            <th>Memory Title</th>
            <th>Created at</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($events as $e)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $e->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $e->eventname }}</td>
                **<td> substr( {{$e->description}}, 0, 24) </td>**
```

This yields:
61  event 40012345  substr( 40012345, 0, 24)
60  event 4001234   substr( event has a very long description. The list should show a 25 char substring., 0, 24)

Thanks...Dan'l

Comment: You can use laravel's string limit helper method for this as `{{ Str::limit($e->description, 25) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorganize your html/php:

```
<td>{{substr($e->description, 0, 24)}}</td>
```

You can also use Laravel Helpers for string related variables. [Read docs here.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-substr)

Comment: Worked great. This old seadog is still learning new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr function for displaying less data:

```
{{ substr($e->description, 0, 24) }}
```

For more information about substr please visit this link:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel inbuilt str helper method

```
{{ Str::limit($e->description, 24, '...') }}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This just gave an unknown function error.